# UART ESP8266 and STM32

Tags: c, stm32, uart, at-command

Hello Im trying to connect a ESP8266 to a STM32 via UART.
I want to use the STM32 to send AT commands to the ESP, so that the ESP can do HTTP GET requests.

The code down here works when I use my PC to send data via FTDI to the STM, then the interrupt is called everytime a byte is recieved.
But when i hook up the ESP8266 I don't get a response even thought im sending `AT\r\n`;

Also i just connected everything like so:

SMT32 Tx -- ESP Rx

ESP Tx -- FTDI Rx

And I sended the AT\r\n command from the SMT to the ESP and on my pc in putty I got the OK command back, so the ESP is responding. But the interrupt is not called.

```c
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"
#include "usbd_cdc_if.h"
 
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
 
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
 
char Rx_Byte[1];        // Creating a single byte buffer
uint8_t Rx_Buffer[256]; // Full buffer
uint8_t Rx_Buffer_Index = 0;
 
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart){
 
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)Rx_Byte, 1);
    memcpy(Rx_Buffer + Rx_Buffer_Index, Rx_Byte, 1);
    Rx_Buffer_Index++;
    if (*Rx_Byte == '\r' || *Rx_Byte == '\n') {
// I could send data via putty and FTDI, and when enter was pressed it printed the data in the buffer back to you via uart
//        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *) Rx_Buffer, Rx_Buffer_Index, 1000);  
        memset(Rx_Buffer, 0, sizeof(Rx_Buffer)); // Clear buffer
        Rx_Buffer_Index = 0;
    }
}
 
int main(void)
{
 
  HAL_Init();
 
  SystemClock_Config();
 
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
 
  char echo_off[] = "ATE0\r\n";
  char data[] = "AT\r\n";
  HAL_Delay(1000);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)echo_off, sizeof(echo_off), 10);
 
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, LED_1_Pin);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*)data, sizeof(data), 1000);
      HAL_Delay(500);
  }
}
```

Comment: No response on serial is typically baud rate or flow control.

Comment: But how does it that is works fine when i use a FTDI adapter and putty? Then i send bytes to the STM32 and i receive them with no problem.

Comment: Minor note: `sizeof(echo_off)` is 7 and not 6 as you expect. `sizeof(data)` is also off by 1 compared to what `HAL_UART_Transmit()` needs.

Comment: Use an oscilloscope to check the signals on the wires.

Comment: Did you try to make prototype using Arduino platform first?

Comment: I did, it was a example file, that used the serial monitor to send data to the ESP, and printed the data it got back

Comment: I checked the baud rate and flow control, and they are all good. dont understand why the interrupt is not called at all